# tables relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, 'users' and 'events'.
Columns in 'users' are 'username', 'email' and 'password'.
Columns in 'events' are 'event', 'date', 'user_id' and 'description'.
I would like a user could register an event using a form.
I have this code in my 'event' class (model 'Event'):

```
class Event extends Eloquent {

  protected $fillable = array(
    'event_id',
    'event', 
    'date', 
    'user_id', 
    'description'
  );

  protected $table = 'events';

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }

}
```

and in my 'user' class (model 'User'):

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

  protected $fillable = array(
    'user_id',
    'username', 
    'email', 
    'password'
  );

  protected $table = 'users';


  public function event()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Event', 'user_id');
  }

}
```

My controller is this:

```
public function postCreateEvent($userId)
{
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
    array(
      'event'       => 'required|alpha_num',
      'date'        => 'required|date',
      'user_id'     => 'required|num',
      'description' => 'required|alpha_num'
    )
  );

  if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::route('users_profile')
      ->with('global', 'Write your data correctly.')
      ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  } else {
    $event       = Input::get('event');
    $date        = Input::get('date');
    $user_id     = Input::get('user_id');
    $description = Input::get('description');

    $user = User::find($userId);

    $event              = new Event;
    $event->event       = $event;
    $event->date        = $date;
    $event->user_id     = $user_id;
    $event->description = $description;
    $event->user()->associate($user);

  if($event->save()) {
    return Redirect::route('users_profile')
      ->with('global', 'Thanks for registering your event.');
  }
}
  return Redirect::route('users_profile')
    ->with('global', 'Try again.');
```

}

I have no errors but the record is not created. Any help? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should also mention the keys because you didn't use the convention that `Laravel` expects by default:

```
// Event Model
public function user()
{
    //return $this->belongsTo('User', 'local_key', 'foreign_key');
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Same goes in `User` model as well and it should be:

```
// User Model
// foreign_key = the key in the child table (user_id)
// local_key = the primary key in User table
return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

### But...

These will not work in your case because you have used same name for `local_key` and `foreign_key` in User table, so try to change the primary key to `id` instead of `user_id` in `users` table and also change the `event_id` to `id` as primary key so your relationship will normally work.

### Try following column structure:

Table `users`:

```
id (Primary key)| username | other fields...
```

Table `events`:

```
id (Primary key)| user_id (foreign key) | event | other fields...
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. Two questions. 1. Is it mandatory to pass the local and foreign key as arguments? And 2. Which key goes first and which one goes second in both models? Thanks.

Comment: It's not mandatory to pass keys unless you follow the convention for primary key and foreign key and the second answer of yo question is already given in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You messed your $event variable.
First you are setting the `$event=Input::get('event');`
Then you resetting it to `$event = new Event;`
Right after you are setting `$event->event=$event`.

Try this one :

```
 $inputEvent       = Input::get('event');
$date        = Input::get('date');
$user_id     = Input::get('user_id');
$description = Input::get('description');

$user = User::find($userId);

$event              = new Event;
$event->event       = $inputEvent;
$event->date        = $date;
$event->user_id     = $user_id;
$event->description = $description;
$event->user()->associate($user);
```

if($event->save()) {